# Choosing test category on command line

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

I am using JUnit's categories to split my tests into different categories and using maven to compile and run my test (surefire and failsafe).

Question is, how to I choose which category of tests are executed from command line?

something like: mvn clean install -DloadTests.

my failsafe plugin:

```
                 <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                <!--Exclude load tests by default-->
                 <excludedGroups>com.test.lib.categories.LoadTestCategory</excludedGroups>
               </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with profiles and specify the plugin configuration in there.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>noLoadTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--Exclude load tests by default-->
                        <excludedGroups>com.test.lib.categories.LoadTestCategory</excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then run maven

```
mvn test -PnoLoadTests
```

If you only ever need to exclude/include one specific category you could also define a property in the profile and use that in the . For more info you can look [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Edit: The other provided answer is the better one in this case, but profiles allow for various advanced configurations.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#groups), user property is called `groups`. Therefore this should work:

`mvn clean install -Dgroups=com.test.lib.categories.LoadTestCategory`